# Hive create table error.

Tags: sql, hive

could you help me overcome the errors I get when I try to create the following table?

Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE RANGE_FT (HOSP_VAR STRING, RANGE INT) 
AS 
            SELECT 'EMR'   ,MAX(emr_avg_score)   - MIN(emr_avg_score)   from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'SCI'   ,MAX(sci_avg_score)   - MIN(sci_avg_score)   from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'ASTH'  ,MAX(asth_avg_score)  - MIN(asth_avg_score)  from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'HF'    ,MAX(hf_avg_score)    - MIN(hf_avg_score)    from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'SC'    ,MAX(sc_avg_score)    - MIN(sc_avg_score)    from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'PNEU'  ,MAX(pneu_avg_score)  - MIN(pneu_avg_score)  from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'PREV'  ,MAX(prev_avg_score)  - MIN(prev_avg_score)  from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'BC'    ,MAX(BC_avg_score)    - MIN(BC_avg_score)    from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'HEART' ,MAX(heart_avg_score) - MIN(heart_avg_score) from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'PREG'  ,MAX(preg_avg_score)  - MIN(preg_avg_score)  from JOIN9
;
```

> line 7:6 missing ALL at 'SELECT'

Comment: try  SET NOCOUNT before query

Comment: Please replace the image with a text (after you paste it, select it and press ctrl+k to format it to code)

Comment: Hi Singh, thank you for your help.  Can you be more spefic about how to set nocount?  I mean where I should put this command. my code is :DROP TABLE RANGE_FT;
CREATE TABLE RANGE_FT
(HOSP_VAR STRING,
RANGE INT)
AS
SELECT 'EMR', MAX(emr_avg_score)- MIN(emr_avg_score) from JOIN9
UNION SELECT 'SCI', MAX(sci_avg_score)- MIN(sci_avg_score) from JOIN9
UNION SELECT 'ASTH', MAX(asth_avg_score) - MIN(asth_avg_score) from JOIN9
UNION SELECT 'HF', MAX(hf_avg_score) - MIN(hf_avg_score) from JOIN9;

Comment: @SinghKailash - `SET NOCOUNT` is a SQL SERVER command (and also not relevant to this issue what so ever)

Comment: Thanks Dudu.  Really appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `UNION` is not supported by your Hive version (and it is also not what you need here).
   Use `UNION ALL` instead.
   https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Union
2. UNION [ALL] requires identical schema from both sides.
   In Hive, unlike other SQL dialects, not just the types should be similar but also the columns aliases.
   https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Union
3. You cannot give a list of columns in your create statement.
   Add the relevant aliases to the SELECT clause.

---

**This is a fixed version of your query**

```
CREATE TABLE RANGE_FT
AS 
                SELECT 'EMR'   as HOSP_VAR ,MAX (emr_avg_score)   - MIN (emr_avg_score)   as RANGE  from JOIN9 
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'SCI'   as HOSP_VAR ,MAX (sci_avg_score)   - MIN (sci_avg_score)   as RANGE  from JOIN9 
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'ASTH'  as HOSP_VAR ,MAX (asth_avg_score)  - MIN (asth_avg_score)  as RANGE  from JOIN9 
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'HF'    as HOSP_VAR ,MAX (hf_avg_score)    - MIN (hf_avg_score)    as RANGE  from JOIN9 
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'SC'    as HOSP_VAR ,MAX (sc_avg_score)    - MIN (sc_avg_score)    as RANGE  from JOIN9 
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'PNEU'  as HOSP_VAR ,MAX (pneu_avg_score)  - MIN (pneu_avg_score)  as RANGE  from JOIN9 
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'PREV'  as HOSP_VAR ,MAX (prev_avg_score)  - MIN (prev_avg_score)  as RANGE  from JOIN9 
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'BC'    as HOSP_VAR ,MAX (BC_avg_score)    - MIN (BC_avg_score)    as RANGE  from JOIN9 
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'HEART' as HOSP_VAR ,MAX (heart_avg_score) - MIN (heart_avg_score) as RANGE  from JOIN9 
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'PREG'  as HOSP_VAR ,MAX (preg_avg_score)  - MIN (preg_avg_score)  as RANGE  from JOIN9
;
```

**And here is an alternative solution with only a single SELECT**

```
create table RANGE_FT
as
select  inline
        (
            array
            (
                struct ('EMR'   ,MAX (emr_avg_score)   - MIN (emr_avg_score)  )
               ,struct ('SCI'   ,MAX (sci_avg_score)   - MIN (sci_avg_score)  )
               ,struct ('ASTH'  ,MAX (asth_avg_score)  - MIN (asth_avg_score) )
               ,struct ('HF'    ,MAX (hf_avg_score)    - MIN (hf_avg_score)   )
               ,struct ('SC'    ,MAX (sc_avg_score)    - MIN (sc_avg_score)   )
               ,struct ('PNEU'  ,MAX (pneu_avg_score)  - MIN (pneu_avg_score) )
               ,struct ('PREV'  ,MAX (prev_avg_score)  - MIN (prev_avg_score) )
               ,struct ('BC'    ,MAX (BC_avg_score)    - MIN (BC_avg_score)   )
               ,struct ('HEART' ,MAX (heart_avg_score) - MIN (heart_avg_score))
               ,struct ('PREG'  ,MAX (preg_avg_score)  - MIN (preg_avg_score) )
            )
        ) as (HOSP_VAR,RANGE)

from    JOIN9    
;
```

Comment: I got a error FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10065]: CREATE TABLE AS SELECT command cannot specify the list of columns for the target table

Comment: I just posted it into text.  Thank you so much for your help Dudu

Comment: Hi Dudu, could you show me your magic about how to create this table?  Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: Hi Dudu,  after I run your code, I got this error. FAILED: SemanticException 4:109 Schema of both sides of union should match. _u1-subquery1-subquery1-subquery1-subquery1-subquery1-subquery1-subquery1-subquery1-subquery2 does not have the field hosp_var. Error encountered near token 'JOIN9'
hive>

Comment: Hi Dudu, You are amazing.  WOW. It works it works.  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Again, thank you so much for the help Dudu. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.As mentioned by Dudu you can not give column name while writing create with select. You can use Union but performance wise UNION ALL is better. Select based on your usecase

```
    CREATE TABLE RANGE_FT 
AS 
            SELECT 'EMR'  AS HOSP_VAR   ,MAX(emr_avg_score)   - MIN(emr_avg_score)  AS `RANGE`  from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'SCI'   AS HOSP_VAR ,MAX(sci_avg_score)   - MIN(sci_avg_score)   AS `RANGE` from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'ASTH'  AS HOSP_VAR ,MAX(asth_avg_score)  - MIN(asth_avg_score)  AS `RANGE` from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'HF'    AS HOSP_VAR ,MAX(hf_avg_score)    - MIN(hf_avg_score)    AS `RANGE` from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'SC'    AS HOSP_VAR ,MAX(sc_avg_score)    - MIN(sc_avg_score)    AS `RANGE` from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'PNEU'  AS HOSP_VAR ,MAX(pneu_avg_score)  - MIN(pneu_avg_score)  AS `RANGE` from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'PREV'  AS HOSP_VAR ,MAX(prev_avg_score)  - MIN(prev_avg_score)  AS `RANGE` from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'BC'    AS HOSP_VAR ,MAX(BC_avg_score)    - MIN(BC_avg_score)    AS `RANGE` from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'HEART' AS HOSP_VAR ,MAX(heart_avg_score) - MIN(heart_avg_score) AS `RANGE` from JOIN9 
    UNION   SELECT 'PREG'  AS HOSP_VAR ,MAX(preg_avg_score)  - MIN(preg_avg_score)  AS `RANGE` from JOIN9
;
```

Comment: Hi Ashish, thanks for your help.  but even I delet the column name and run the code, the error still shows like this FAILED: ParseException line 4:12 missing ALL at 'SELECT' near '<EOF>'
line 5:12 missing ALL at 'SELECT' near '<EOF>'

Comment: @QingZhang Please alias the column name and put Range column  in backslash `